# c# web Api mvc working with multiple table with stored procedure but only one model class

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi i'm new in developing .NET Web APi MVC using SQL Server(Stored Procedure). For register stored procedure, i'm trying to add same data to different table. I have a few question, Can i have only one Model class for two different table? i'm currently using one model class for two different table,  Or should i create another model class for another table? Did my implementation of MVC are right? i've create services file for doing the logic for controller to implement the logic.

**Store procedure**

```
USE [HISDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SSO_Register]    Script Date: 2/2/2021 2:24:23 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SSO_Register]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @customer_id nvarchar(255),
    @secure_word nvarchar(255),
    @full_name nvarchar(255),
    @phone_number nvarchar(255),
    @nationality nvarchar(255),
    @id_number nvarchar(255),
    @dob nvarchar(255),
    @email nvarchar(255),
    @user_id nvarchar(255),
    @provider_id nvarchar(255),
    @temp_token nvarchar(255),
    @tac nvarchar(6),
    @gender nvarchar(255)


AS
BEGIN

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH;

    UPDATE ST_YIBANCANSHU SET @customer_id = (SELECT CONCAT(parmvalstr1, FORMAT(parmvalint,parmvalstr2), '_', YEAR(GETDATE())) FROM ST_YIBANCANSHU WHERE parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'), 
            parmvalint = parmvalint + 1
            WHERE parmtyp = 'RUNNING_NUM' AND parmkey = 'GUKE'
    
     -- Insert statements for procedure here
     INSERT INTO SSO (CUSTOMER_ID,SECURE_WORD,FULL_NAME,PHONE_NUMBER,NATIONALITY,ID_NUMBER,DOB,EMAIL,GENDER)
     VALUES
     (@customer_id,@secure_word,@full_name,@phone_number,@nationality,@id_number,@dob,@email,@gender)

     INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_INFO (CUSTOMER_ID,USER_ID,PROVIDER_ID,TEMP_TOKEN,TAC)
     VALUES
     (@customer_id,@user_id,@provider_id,@temp_token,@tac)

END
```

**SSO Model**

```
public class SSO_Model
    {
        
        public string customer_id { get; set; }
        public string full_name { get; set; }
        public string secure_word { get; set; }
        public string phone_number { get; set; }
        public string gender { get; set; }
        public string id_number { get; set; }
        public string dob { get; set; }
        public string nationality { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string provider_id { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        
    }
```

**doRegister method**

```
bool _return = false;
            try
            {
                string tac = " ";
                string temp_token = " ";
                Test util = new Test();
                tac = Test.getTac();
                temp_token = Test.generateTempToken(objsso.email, objsso.secure_word);
               

                SqlParameter[] parm =
                {
                    //new SqlParameter("customer_id", customer_id),
                    new SqlParameter("full_name", objsso.full_name),
                    new SqlParameter("phone_number", objsso.phone_number),
                    new SqlParameter("gender", objsso.gender),
                    new SqlParameter("id_number", objsso.id_number),
                    new SqlParameter("secure_word", objsso.secure_word),
                    new SqlParameter("nationality", objsso.nationality),
                    new SqlParameter("dob", objsso.dob),
                    
                    new SqlParameter("email", objsso.email),
                    new SqlParameter("user_id", objsso.email),
                    
                    new SqlParameter("provider_id", objsso.provider_id),
                    new SqlParameter("temp_token", temp_token),
                    new SqlParameter("tac", tac)
                 
            };
                var connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
                ConnectionStrings["_cs"].ConnectionString;

                dbUtil db = new dbUtil(connectionString);
                db.ExecNonQuery("SSO_Register", parm);
                _return = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _return = false;
                throw ex;
            }
            return _return;
```

**Controller class**

```
public IHttpActionResult Register(SSO_Model sso)
        {
            
            String respCode = "";
            String respMessage = " ";
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    SSOService sso_service = new SSOService();

                    if (sso_service.doRegister(sso))
                    {
                        respCode = Constant.RESP_SUCCESSFUL;
                        respMessage = Constant.RESP_SUCCESSFUL_MESSAGE;
                        return Ok(sso);
                        
                    }
                }

                return Ok(sso);
            }
            catch
            {
                
                respCode = Constant.RESP_INVALID_REQUEST;
                respMessage = Constant.RESP_INVALID_REQUEST_MESSAGE;
                string response = " ResponseCode:" + respCode + " Response Message:" +respMessage;
                return Ok(response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"`@id_number nvarchar(255),`"*? What "number" is made up of non-numbers, and especially one's outside of the base code page? Why are ***all*** of your parameters an `nvarchar(255)`? You do know there are *other* data types, right?

Comment: id_number is an identification number. It consists "-" character. For Example 941101-41-212 . @Larnu

Comment: But `'-'` is available in every collation for a `varchar`; so why (again), are all your parameters an `nvarchar`? `@dob nvarchar(255)` that's clearly a date of birth, so why do you need 255 UTF-16 characters (totalling 510 bytes in size) to store a date? A `date` is 3 bytes in size... Literally well over 100 times smaller.

Comment: should i use varchar? i use nvarchar because it's seems the default parameters for string.

Comment: No, [varchar is NOT a one size fits all data type](https://wp.larnu.uk/fundamentals-varchar-is-not-a-one-size-fits-all-data-type/)... There are 6 date and time data types, for example, and 5 of them are infinitely better for a date of birth than a `(n)varchar`.